# MvxListView is not smooth like the normal xamarin List view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

MvxListView in the following layout (SearchLayoutView) is not smooth like the normal xamarin List view. Items are freezing when I scroll down the list .Here I am binding a Template (search_list_item) as Item. so properties from Model are bound with the layout properties.  Is that the reason for this behavior? How can I slow down the scroll speed? Will it fix this problem? Can anyone please suggest a way to fix this ?

I am using Xamarin Android 4.18.1,Mvvm Cross 3.2.1

**SearchLayoutView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyAPP.Droid"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearSearchResultView"
        android:background="@color/graySerachView">
        <TextView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbutton"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:editable="false"
            android:id="@+id/MainSearchResultView"
            android:gravity="fill"
            local:MvxBind="Text SearchString" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Search Result"
            android:id="@+id/textViewResultCount" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load More "
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/SearchprogressView"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ListSearchResult"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearSearchResultView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/SearchprogressView"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Item"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/search_list_item"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**search_list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyAPP.Droid"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutItem"
    android:background="@drawable/border">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/GridSearchMain">
        <Mvx.MvxImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageSearchProducts"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            local:MvxBind="Bitmap ProductImageUrl, Converter=ImageView" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TextSearchProductName"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
            local:MvxBind="Text ProductName" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TextSearchUnitPrice"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            local:MvxBind="Text UnitPrice" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TextSearchProductId"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            local:MvxBind="Text ProductId" />
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment code**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            try
            {

                if (_rooView != null)
                {
                    var viewGroup = (ViewGroup) _rooView.Parent;
                    viewGroup.RemoveView(_rooView);

                    //Get ViewModel
                    var viewModel = (SearchResultViewModel) ViewModel;
                    //Bind to List View.
                    _rooView.
                        FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.ListSearchResult).ItemsSource = viewModel.Item;

                    return _rooView;
                }

                var ingnore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                _rooView = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_serach_result, null);

                return _rooView;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var dialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity);
                dialogAlert.SetMessage(exception.Message);
                dialogAlert.Show();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be because image is loaded synchronously?

Comment: @Miha Markic.Thanks but i tried by removing imagView.But again same issue is out there

Comment: Does the new Xamarin profiler help? Can you make the list scroll smoother by removing bits one-by-one? That might help identify what the problem is - whether it's something being bound or resized or something else...

Comment: @Stuart. I didn't try Xamarin profiler yet.But As you correctly mentioned ,i tried to remove everything bit by bit.I removed everything until the list item with a plain text View.But no luck.What about this template binding?Are their any well known issues exist for template binding comparing with normal adapter way?

Comment: Remove the nesting. Give your items a fixed height that will keep redraws to a minimum. If that does not help profile it to see what is going on.

Comment: @Cheesebaron. Thank you .I have found that the Converter method for Image view is called again and again when we scroll the List view.Why it is happen again while image view is already loaded with the image.?how can we stop this behavior?

Comment: The Converter will be called whenever the row is first used, when it is removed from the display (because it scrolls out of view) or when it is assigned a new datasource (when the row is reused). But if `I removed everything until the list item with a plain text View.But no luck.` is true, then your problem is nothing to do with the converter...

Comment: @Stuart Ok .But without removing  all the controls ,I removed the converter from the MvxImageView .Then bound the Url to "ImageUrl" property .Now the List is smooth but image is not rendering.Eg Like this  
            local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ProductImageUrl"

Comment: So well done - you've found the issue - the problem is in your ImageView binding... if you are synchronously loading the image, then it's going to be slow - the standard `ImageUrl` binding does the image display asynchronously.

Comment: @Stuart.Thank you. But standard ImageUrl binding is not updating the UI. I mean i doesn't show the Image from the URL.I can see  that Url(Url is actually a web url not a local one) is properly bound to ImageUrl .How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha ! As Stuart mentioned above, I have checked the standard ImageUrl binding. I was missing "Download file plugin" and "download cache plugin". I have installed all these from the Nuget. Now Standard binding is working properly. List view also smooth like normal android ListView.

So the problem is MvxImageView was downloading the images synchronously while I use the converter. But the standard binding is doing it asynchronously.

Thanks to Miha Markic also, you already mentioned the point in the comment as well.